# How to place a tab in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, ionic4

Is it possible to place ion-tab at the middle of the screen in ionic 4.I have an image with some text on the top of the page.Is it possible to place ion-tabs at the middle of the screen that is beneath the image and content.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="center">
    <ion-tab-button tab="schedule">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="speakers">
      <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Speakers</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="map">
      <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="about">
      <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>About</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: As long I know there is only two slots: bottom and top, but try with ion-fab might work as you want.

Comment: Please share the entire code that you have so far? It seems like you are trying to apply a tool (ion-tab-bar) that was not made for your use case - but if you could share full context there is definitely a good way to achieve what you need without a hack;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use ion-segment, is probably the best option here.
[api here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment)